# SQL CLR - Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.2 not loading dependant assemblies

Tags: sql-server, exchangewebservices, sqlclr, ews-managed-api

I am attempting to use the EWSMA 2.2 with my SQL Server 2016 (v 13.0.2164.0) to connect to an Exchange server 2010. The code I've written works perfectly as a console app, but when I try to turn it into a SQL CLR Assembly, it fails at runtime with the following error:

```
 Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "EXT_ExchangeCalendar": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
```

I have moved my the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll and  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll to the  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ directory.  Then I've added the assembly to SQL Server using this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [microsoft.exchange.webservices] AUTHORIZATION dbo FROM 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

Upon execution it returns that error.  I suspect that this has to do with the primary assembly being unable to load the  dependancy (...Auth.dll) but I can't verify that.

My other suspicion is that CLR doesn't support the version of .NET that is required for this DLL?  Any thoughts?

UPDATE:  Here's the source code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;


public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{




    public class TableObj
    {
        public SqlString startdate;
        public SqlString enddate;
        public SqlString subject;
        public SqlString appointmenttype;
        public SqlString body;
        public SqlString categories;
        public SqlString location;

        public TableObj(SqlString in_startdate, SqlString in_enddate, SqlString in_subject, SqlString in_appointmenttype, SqlString in_body, SqlString in_categories, SqlString in_location)
        {
            startdate = in_startdate;
            enddate = in_enddate;
            subject = in_subject;
            appointmenttype = in_appointmenttype;
            body = in_body;
            categories = in_categories;
            location = in_location;
        }

    }



    [SqlFunction(
     TableDefinition = "startdate nvarchar(max), enddate nvarchar(max), subject nvarchar(max), appointmenttype nvarchar(max), body nvarchar(max), categories nvarchar(max), location nvarchar(max)",
     FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]



    public static IEnumerable EXT_ExchangeCalendar(DateTime startdate = default(DateTime)
                                                  , DateTime enddate = default(DateTime)
                                                  , String username = "myusername"
                                                  , String password = "mypassword"
                                                  , String domain = "mydomain"
                                                  , String url = "https://owa.mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
    {



        startdate = startdate == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.Now : startdate;
        enddate = enddate == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) : enddate;







            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domain);
            service.Url = new Uri(url);

            ArrayList tableResults = new ArrayList();
            const int NUM_APPTS = 5000;

            CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
            CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startdate, enddate, NUM_APPTS);

            FindItemsResults<Item> instanceResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, cView);


            foreach (Item item in instanceResults.Items)
            {
                item.Load(); //necessary to load the body into the appointment.
                Appointment appointment = item as Appointment;

                tableResults.Add(new TableObj(appointment.Start.ToString(), appointment.End.ToString(), appointment.Subject.ToString(), appointment.AppointmentType.ToString(), appointment.Body.ToString(), appointment.Categories.ToString(), appointment.Location.ToString()));


            }




            return new ArrayList(tableResults);


    }





    public static void FillRow(
          object obj,
          out SqlString startdate,
          out SqlString enddate,
          out SqlString subject,
          out SqlString appointmenttype,
          out SqlString body,
          out SqlString categories,
          out SqlString location)
    {
        TableObj myRow = (TableObj)obj;

        startdate = myRow.startdate;
        enddate = myRow.enddate;
        subject = myRow.subject;
        appointmenttype = myRow.appointmenttype;
        body = myRow.body;
        categories = myRow.categories;
        location = myRow.location;
    }



    private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
        bool result = false;

        Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

        // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
        // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
        // to encrypt the authentication credentials.
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }




    private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
    object sender,
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
        if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
        if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
        {
            if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
            {
                foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                       (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                    {
                        // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid.
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                        {
                            // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                            // so the method returns false.
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are
            // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
            // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // In all other cases, return false.
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Are there other dependent DLLs? When you load a DLL, it will attempt to load all dependencies from the same folder (if not already in SQL Server). If those dependencies aren't in the same folder, it will error. Also, if any of the DLLs is mixed-mode (i.e. not pure-MSIL), then it isn't loadable no matter what. Since you are on SQL Server 2016, you can load DLLs linked to CLR v4.0, which includes Framework versions starting at 4.0.

Comment: There is a second dll that handles Auth functions for the WebServices.dll.  I don't know if it is pure MSIL or not.  How would i figure that out?

Comment: Not sure how to determine that ;-). Typically it is a different error message, so maybe not the issue here. The error does mention `The path is not of a legal form.`. Were there other DLLs that you didn't copy to the new location? Can you try loading from the original location? Is the Database set to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`?

Comment: Both the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll and Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll are in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ directory.  I copied everything from the EWSMA's folder to the v4.0.. folder.  Just to make sure its not that. :-(  The database it definitely set to Trustworthy ON.

Comment: In the SQL Server logs, it shows that it successful loaded the assemblies, too... 

11/14/2016 15:02:51,spid63,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.exchange.webservices<c/> version=15.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 274 (Utilities.dbo[runtime].273).

11/14/2016 15:02:51,spid63,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'exchange_clr_sqlclr<c/> version=0.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=f776ca953d8c1d95<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 274 (Utilities.dbo[runtime].273).

Comment: Well, that makes sense since it is a run-time error. You might need to attach Visual Studio debugger to the sqlservr.exe process to see what it is attempting to do in `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase` when you instantiate the new `ExchangeService`. BTW: why are you passing back dates as `SqlString` instead of `SqlDateTime`?

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can do that.  I actually switched it back to SqlDateTime after I posted this - I was attempting to use EWS MA 1.2 with .Net 3.5, so I removed  most of the date stuff to attempt to see if I could get it work....  But then I found out that EWSMA 1.2 doesn't support the CalendarView.